# Reading CSI matrix complex numbers from .mat file in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I've been trying to explore the topic of human activity detection using WiFi signals. This website (http://tns.thss.tsinghua.edu.cn/wifiradar/index_en.html#fh5co-press) provides data sets with of CSI readings in .mat format. I would like to import those values into something like a Numpy array or Pandas DataFrame to analyze the data and possibly do some machine learning tasks.

Here's how I read the file:

```
d = scipy.io.loadmat(file)
d.keys(): 
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'csi_data', 'gt_trace', 
'init_loc', 'rx_loc', 'ts_data', 'tx_loc'])
```

I am interested in the csi_data field. in that field, all csi arrays containing complex numbers are concatenated after each other:

```
array([[array([[ -4.50318786 +8.44347724j,   5.62898483+10.69507118j,
     13.50956359 +1.12579697j, ...,  -4.50318786 +1.12579697j,
     -0.56289848 +3.3773909j ,   0.56289848 +2.25159393j],
   [  7.8805554  +3.37738089j,  10.13214266 -6.19186496j,
      0.        -12.94662673j, ...,   2.25158726 +3.9402777j ,
      3.37738089 +0.j        ,   2.25158726 -1.12579363j],
   [  6.7553659  -5.62947158j,  -0.56294716-11.82189032j,
    -12.38483747 -4.50357726j, ...,   4.50357726 -1.12589432j,
      0.56294716 -3.37768295j,  -0.56294716 -2.81473579j],
   ...,
   [ -9.00567956 -6.75425967j, -13.50851934 +3.37712983j,
     -5.62854972+14.63422928j, ...,   2.25141989 -5.62854972j,
     -2.81427486 -3.37712983j,  -3.37712983 -1.12570994j],
   [ -7.31688093 -9.00539191j, -12.94525087 +0.56283699j,
```

when I try the len() it returns 1, and so all the key,value iterating methods didn't work on this, because they're treating it as a single field.

I would like to have each array in a single row with a numerical index (0,1,...)
I appreciate any help! thanks in advance

Comment: `len` just gives the first dimension.  With `numpy` arrays `arr.shape` is more useful (more like MATLAB `size`).  If the `shape` is (1,1) (and `dtype` is `object`) that means you have an array wrapping another array.  Try `arr.item()` to get at the inner one.

Comment: `loadmat` has to convert MATLAB structures into Python ones.  MATLAB matrices become `numpy` arrays (`ndarray`).  `cells` become object dtype arrays.  `structs` become `structured` arrays.  Be prepared to poke around.  Check `shape` and `dtype` (again and again).